# Vue.js don't know how to pass props to map() function and looping components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am beginner at Vue and i am trying to convert this **React** piece of code in to my **Vue** App and i am struggling to fix it. I'm looping an object with map() function and passing props to it.

**React**:

```
<div className='directory-menu'>
  {this.state.sections.map(({ id, ...otherSectionProps }) => (
    <MenuItem key={id} {...otherSectionProps} />
  ))}
</div>
```

And i have this state object:

```
 this.state = {
      sections: [
        {
          title: 'hats',
          imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png',
          id: 1,
          linkUrl: 'hats'
        }, // the other elements continue
```

And in **Vue** I want to do the same thing:

```
<template>
  <div class="directory-menu">
    {{ 
     sections.map(() => (
      <MenuItem :key="sections.id" v-bind="sections" />
     ))
    }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Data where props are coming from:

```
<script>
  import MenuItem from '../Menu-Item/MenuItem.vue';
  export default {
    components:{
      MenuItem
    },
    data(){
      return{
        sections: [
          {
            title: 'hats',
            imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png',
            id: 1,
            linkUrl: 'hats'
          }, // the other elements continue
```

I don't know if i am failing to spread the props with spread operator **v-bind** or something else that i am missing.

Comment: In vue you use v-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-for` in vuejs to render a list :

```
<div class="directory-menu">
    <MenuItem  v-for="section in sections" :key="section.id"/>
</div>
```